# getting unexpected output from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating wishlist where I am sending data via ajax but it's not returning data as I implemented in the code I fail to figure out what is the main reason behind this. Here is the code

```
<li><span><i style="color:red;" class="<?php
                   if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
                   $selwishlist = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM wishlist WHERE user_id =:userid and product_id =:productid ");
                   $selwishlist->bindParam(":userid",$userid);
                   $selwishlist->bindParam(":productid",$id);
                   $selwishlist->execute();
                   $selresultwishlis = $selwishlist->rowCount();
                   if($selresultwishlis > 0){
                   echo "fa fa-heart";}else{
                       echo "ion-android-favorite-outline";
                   }}else{
                       echo "ion-android-favorite-outline";
                   }
                    ?> wishlist-click" id="wishlist-product-id-<?php echo $id; ?>"></i></span>
                </li>


if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $userdetail = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email");
    $userdetail->bindParam(":email",$email);
    $userdetail->execute();
    $userres = $userdetail->fetch();   
    $userid = $userres['id'];
    }
    else{
        $email = '';
        $userid = '';
    }
```

This is my input button Where first I check if the session is running or not an then check if the item is in the user wishlist or not and according to that I change the class of wishlist icon

```
 $(".wishlist-click").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var el = $(this);   
alert('I am clicked')    
var ids = this.id;
var splitids = ids.split('-');
var wishlistid = splitids[3];
 
 $.ajax({
      url:'wishlistajax.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:{ids:wishlistid},
      success:function(response){
          if(response == 1){
              alert('1');
          }else if(response == '0'){
              alert('0');
          }else if(response == '3'){
            alert('its 3');
         }
         else{
              alert('Not in All');
          }
          
      }    
    });    
});
```

This is my jquery code and I am getting Not in both in response AND HERE IS MY AJAX CODE

```
  <?php 
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['email'])){
    echo "1";
 exit();
if(isset($_POST['ids'])){
    
    
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];  
    
    
    $productid = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ids']);
    include "conn.php";
    $userdetail = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = :email");
    $userdetail->bindParam(":email",$email);
    $userdetail->execute();
    $userres = $userdetail->fetch();   
    $userid = $userres['id'];
   
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];    
        
    $insertquery = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO wishlist (product_id, user_id) VALUES (:productid, :userid)");
    $insertquery->bindParam(":productid",$productid);
    $insertquery->bindParam(":userid",$userid);    
    $insertquery->execute();
    echo 'Item added';
        exit();
    }}
    else{
        echo '2';
        header("location:loginregister.php");
         exit();
    }
     echo '3';
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: You are not return 1 or 0 from the server side. So the code you wrote works fine. 
Just `console.log(response)` and post the result here.

Comment: I am getting my HTML code of whole page in the console

Comment: and getting not in both in alert

Comment: If you only want to return a specific value, make sure you don't output anything else on that page/response. If you do, it will be a part of the response. You should also remove your "header()" call. Now you're echoing a value and then redirect away.

Comment: i am just using 1 and 0 for testing sake

Comment: Try to put `exit();` after `echo` and check the logs. You continue to run the PHP script even after the echo.

Comment: when the session is not availble it should redirect to login page but its not redirecting there

Comment: You should return a value to the Ajax Response. Then you handle the redirection in Javascript. Remove `header()` redirect from PHP Script.

Comment: still getting not in both and all page HTML code in response

Comment: but I also could redirect from here I have done this in my other code and that's working just fine but in my testing, I should get 1 or 0 because there is only 1 if and 1 else . if if the condition is false its should go on else and return 0 but it's not returning either 1 or nor 0

Comment: Have you exit the script after every echo ?

Comment: yes i have exit after every echo